# How to retrieve the Capture Instance for a given table?

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

Working with SQL Server 2012, I have a hierarchical table layout (TPT). All tables "inherit" from the same base table (`dbo.DataObjects`). All tables have history tracking via CDC enabled.

I am trying to write a generic function that returns the CDC history information for a give type including the relevant information from all base tables.

Supposing my type is `User` with the table `dbo.Users` which inherits directly from `dbo.DataObjects`, my query should look something like this:

```
DECLARE @Begin_LSN binary(10),@End_LSN binary(10) 
SELECT @Begin_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Users') 
SELECT @End_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn() 
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_DataObjects(@Begin_LSN, @End_LSN,'ALL') AS a 
JOIN cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Users(@Begin_LSN, @End_LSN,'ALL') AS b 
ON a.__$start_lsn = b.__$start_lsn
WHERE ID = 10;
```

This will give me the complete history trail for the User with ID 10 including the columns from the base table.

Now I want to build this kind of query dynamically.

One of my problems is that the cdc functions to retrieve the history information include the name of the capture instance:

```
cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>
```

I also need the name of the capture instance in the second line to get the min lsn:

```
sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('<capture_instance>')
```

The capture instance name either gets created automatically for me when I enable CDC for a table or is passed manually. If I don't want to keep track of the capture instance name myself, **is there a way to retrieve the name of the capture instance for a given table**?

I am aware that there can be more than one capture instance per table (max. 2 I think), but I likely always will only use one per table.

PS: I am also aware that the capture instance name is usually built in the way `<schema>_<table>`, but relying on this assumption seems a bit risky. The naming convention could change for future versions, or someone could supply a manual capture instance name / change the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Input (hopefully stored procedure parameters):

```
DECLARE @table1 NVARCHAR(513) = N'dbo.Users',
        @table2 NVARCHAR(513) = N'dbo.DataObjects',
        @ID     INT = 10;
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @InstanceName1 NVARCHAR(513),
        @InstanceName2 NVARCHAR(513),
        @Begin_LSN     BINARY(10),
        @End_LSN       BINARY(10);

SELECT @InstanceName1 = c.capture_instance
  FROM cdc.change_tables AS c
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON c.[source_object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = PARSENAME(@table1,1)
    AND s.name = PARSENAME(@table1,2);

SELECT @InstanceName2 = c.capture_instance
  FROM cdc.change_tables AS c
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON c.[source_object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = PARSENAME(@table2,1)
    AND s.name = PARSENAME(@table2,2);

SELECT @Begin_LSN = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(@InstanceName1), 
       @End_LSN   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn();

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT * 
  FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_' + @InstanceName2
  + '(@b, @l, ''ALL'') AS a 
  INNER JOIN cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_' + @InstanceName1
  + '(@b, @l, ''ALL'') AS b 
  ON a.__$start_lsn = b.__$start_lsn
  WHERE a.ID = @ID;';
  ------^ guessing here

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
  N'@b BINARY(10), @l BINARY(10), @ID INT',
  @Begin_LSN, @End_LSN, @ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

object_id() function is your friend:

```
declare @capture_instance sysname
select @capture_instance = capture_instance 
from cdc.change_tables where source_object_id = object_id('dbo.myTable)
```