# Delayed availability of historical data when using CDC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I am using the SQL Change Data Capture feature to retrieve historical data from my tables.

During testing, I noticed that when I insert/update a row and query the change data right afterwards (see my [earlier question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61801/how-to-retrieve-the-capture-instance-for-a-given-table/61804) on how I do that), the result will turn up empty.

I played around with it and noticed that if I wait 10 seconds between the data manipulation and the history query, the history will be up to date.

I am aware that CDC functionality is based on the transaction logs somehow and that this probably is the reason why there is a delay between data changes and the cdc history table being updated.

Now my question:

- Is this delay somewhere explained in the CDC documentation? I could not find any mention of it.
- **Is there a way to manually make sure that the history table is up to date before I query it? (somehow triggering CDC to check the logs?)**
- How does CDC work together with transactions? Will I for example be able to query historical data that I have overwritten in the same transaction? Or does the transaction first have to commit for the cdc data to become availalbe?

Answer (score 2):

CDC relies on a SQL Server Agent job to capture information from the transaction log. You can customize the job parameters by updating `msdb.dbo.cdc_jobs` - there are multiple properties as described in [this Books Online topic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645592.aspx#Capture):

- `maxtrans`
- `maxscans`
- `continuous`
- `pollinginterval`

That doc has some information about these parameters, as does [this white paper](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd266396%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

But really, CDC is not meant to be a real-time system, and you should use caution adjusting these parameters too much to make it so. Most people acknowledge that you need to wait to let CDC catch up (see [here](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/using-sql-server-2008-change-data-capture/) and [here](http://brockbeatty.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/sql-server-2008-cdc-tips-and-tricks-2/)). If 5-10 seconds is not fast enough for you, you might be using the wrong technology.

As for the separate transaction question, this is something you could test, no?

Comment: _As for the separate transaction question, this is something you could test, no?_ Indeed, that was what I was doing, when the delay problem turned up and distorted my results. Now I am not sure anymore if I am testing right. ;) But you are right, I will run some tests with a big enough delay and hope I am not missing something.

Comment: So far my tests seem to indicate that the transaction has to be committed before the history data appears in the CDC table. So I guess there is no way to read it from the same transaction.